# How do I change Timestamps into just date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pysimplegui

I'm new to Python, so forgive my ignorance
I'm using pysimplegui to build a project tracker to help organize my work.

I've tried manually converting each date value within the list, but it tends to print the values incorrectly, and breaks them out of the list, when I'm trying to build the table.

I'm hoping there is a global way to change the date format used from "Timestamp" to "Date" or "Datetime".

My current code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime



Excel_Read = pd.read_excel('C:\pythonProject\Schedule\Project_Schedule.xlsx', sheet_name='Schedule')

schedule_headings = ['Priority', 'Project_Name','Project_Num','Due_Date','Sales','Engineer','PM/PC' ]

Schedule_Table = pd.DataFrame(schedule_headings)
Schedule_List = Excel_Read.values.tolist()


def create_schedule(schedule_info_array, schedule_headings):
    schedule_info_window_layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=Schedule_List, headings=schedule_headings, max_col_width=35,
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  justification='Left',
                  num_rows=10,
                  enable_events=True,
                  enable_click_events=True,
                  key='-SCHEDULE_TABEL-',
                  row_height=35)]
    ]

    Schedule_info_window = sg.Window('Schedule Info', schedule_info_window_layout, modal=True)

    while True:
        event, values = Schedule_info_window.read()
        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        if event == '-SCHEDULE_TABEL-':
            print(values['-SCHEDULE_TABEL-'][0])
            #name = Schedule_List[(values['-SCHEDULE_TABEL-'][0])][4],
            #print(type(Schedule_List[0][3]))
            #print(Schedule_List)
```

[Image of GUI and time format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaADP.png)

Comment: Use following piece of code: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due_Date']).dt.date. This creates a new column with your desired format.

Comment: I don't have "df" defined, is this different module? 
I also am not sure where I would put this in my code. Since my "Schedule_list" is already built, would it go into the "sg.Table" and layout section, so it would replace it before it builds the GUI?

No it doesn't Rene, that seems to be when it imports the values of the date as a float. I have the date format importing, but its coming in as a "Timestamp" and giving me hours, minutes and seconds after the date, all set to zeros.

Comment: `df` is the variable used by default for 99% of people using pandas to make a DataFrame, and it the example used in most documentation. You'll replace it with whatever you call yours.

Comment: I'd suggest looking up and going through a `pandas` tutorial before trying to implement it into a whole new program.